# How to process file line by line in multiple threads and one thread for each line in c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, file

I've created a c# WPF project, I've to process a csv file having some records which may not be limited to few hundreds or few thousands or millions. I need to read the line of record, then process the record which generally takes 5 to 10 seconds and then update the record with new value.

The operation consists of a network call to server through web service, the server then calls another server to connect to authority server, the authority server responds back with data in the same loop as requested. The authority takes time because it is having a very large database consists of about one billion records. So, to encrypt decrypt and authenticate operation takes about 5-10 seconds to process completely.

I can not perform the operation in one thread as for processing whole file may take months so I want to create hundreds of threads which will process the data. The approach I'm thinking is that I'm trying to create a thread which creates threads up to 100 and monitors them for free threads if available. When a thread returns data after process then it writes it in file and create new thread for new line to process.

This approach I'm thinking seems to be too complex, should I implement the same and how or how should I resolve the problem.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I see no indication that the OP is bound by OP work. It's *processing* the record which takes 5-10 seconds, and we don't know what that processing consists of.

Comment: @JonSkeet OP thinks reading each line on a dedicated thread will help boost performance.

Comment: What does the processing consist of? If you're CPU-bound, then creating 100s of threads probably isn't a good idea. If you're waiting for a web service or something similar, can *that* scale to hundreds of parallel requests? Either Parallel LINQ or TPL Dataflow may be appropriate here.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: No, the OP thinks that *processing* each line on a dedicated thread will help boost performance, and it may well.

Comment: @JonSkeet It may, of course. But the OPs question is too vague.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Sure, more detail is required. But just *assuming* that the OP is IO-bound seems less helpful than asking for more details.

Comment: You are likely looking to re-implement `Parallel.For` / `Parallel.ForEach`, but whole thing sound very strange (especially read/write one line in CSV file at a time part).

Comment: Actually the processing consists of authenticating the record from a network server which takes and not CPU or network bound.

Comment: A network server call *is* IO bound. That can scale pretty well if you look into asynchronous patterns. Can you network server handle concurrent requests? Do you know what the limit is?

Comment: What type of processing are you doing that take 5 to 7 seconds.  I would try to speed up the processing rather than go to multithreading.

Comment: The authentication is done by a webservice which calls another server to ask the authority and finally authority authenticates the data which is returned back the same with y or n.

Comment: I'm having 100 MBPS leased line connected to authority server so , I think I can't much boost the network operation.

Comment: The network server can handle multiple requests with very large number of requests at a time. The authority takes time because their database consists of about one billion records of the whole country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options that can help you here:

- [Parallel LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx)

Parallel LINQ is the simpler option, but provides a lot less customization. It would look something like:

```
var results = File.ReadLines("input.csv")
                  .AsParallel()
                  .AsOrdered()
                  .WithDegreeOfParallelism(100)
                  .Select(ProcessLine);

File.WriteAllLines("output.csv", results);
```

(You need to implement the `ProcessLine` method, of course.)

Now that will give you a lot of parallelism, but probably via lots of threads which are blocked a lot of the time... whereas a more sophisticated solution would end up using asynchronous IO so that actually you probably hardly need any actual *threads*.

One thing to be aware of: if you're making *web* requests over the network, you may need to configure the maximum number of requests you can make in parallel to the host. See [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) and the [`<connectionManagement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx) settings element.

Comment: Thank You so much. @Jon Skeet